# What to do if in an equation there are uncertainty on both sides when solving for a variable?

Tags: thermodynamics, error-analysis

So i did an experiment which requires me to calculate the specific heat capacity of copper. To do that i equate the quantity of heat loss by copper and quantity of heat gained by water. (heated copper was placed into water)

So using the heat formula and based on the data i have collected:
q=mass x specific heat capacity x (temperature initial- temperature final 
-q copper = q water

$-(-0.625878 $ x $c) ± 0.002 = 208.1814 ± 29.79 $

Here what should i do for the uncertainties? I would need divide $208$ by $0.6$ to find c so should i divide the uncertinty $-29.79$ by $0.002$ too? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Rearranging, $c=\frac{Q}{m\Delta T}$. Now find the uncertainty on a quotient using standard error-propagation formulas.

Comment: @probably_someone what are error-propagation formulas and what i did was wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, it just won't help you do anything useful. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulas